# How can I convert list into datetime with miliseconds?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, datetime

I have these numbers in a list of strings:

```
2018,12,12,11,10,38.971
```

and I would like to convert it into:

```
2018/12/12 11:10:38.971
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse it without modifying the string, specifying the format 
for the [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) appropriately:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: s = "2018,12,12,11,10,38.971"

In [3]: datetime.strptime(s, "%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S.%f")
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 12, 11, 10, 38, 971000)
```

If your input is a list, you could "str.join" the items in the list first and then use `.strptime()`:

```
In [10]: l = ['2018', '12', '12', '11', '10', '38.971']

In [11]: s = ",".join(l)

In [12]: datetime.strptime(s, "%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S.%f")
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 12, 11, 10, 38, 971000)
```

Comment: They said "list of strings", so I'd suggest calling `','.join(lst)` before passing it to strptime.

Comment: My s = ['2018', '12', '12', '11', '20', '28.079']

Comment: @CharlesWagner yeah, then second option in the answer is something you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime's `strftime` with datetime's `strptime`, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

lst = ['2018','12','12','11','10','38.971']
d = ' '.join(lst)

print(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y %m %d %H %M %S.%f').strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%m:%S.%f'))
# 2018/12/12 11:12:38.971000
```